# What does the -c in wget -c Linux command mean?

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I am installing Artifactory on an Ubuntu server, and trying to add JFrog repository key. The command is:

```
wget -c -O- "https://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=jfrog" | sudo apt-key add
```

I am getting an error saying that `wget -c: command not found`!

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html

Comment: Do you really have a dash after the O

Comment: @Colt yes, that's a dash, and that's very common.

Comment: @MichaelHampton common _after_ the option?

Comment: @Colt Yes, of course.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I see it now

Answer (score 1):

`wget --help` shows you:

```
-c,  --continue                  resume getting a partially-downloaded file
     --start-pos=OFFSET          start downloading from zero-based position OFFSET
     --progress=TYPE             select progress gauge type
     --show-progress             display the progress bar in any verbosity mode
```

Your error messages (wget Command not found) means that wget is not installed. Run `sudo apt-get install wget` to install it.

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part is that you get the error message

> wget -c: command not found

The `-c` part shouldn't be there.

Normally, if don't have wget installed the resulting error message would be:

> wget: command not found

So, for some reason your shell thinks that you want to run a command named `wget -c`.

If you copied and pasted that command, retype it (don't copy and paste it). Most probably there is an invisible utf8 character between the `wget` and the `-c`, resulting in the shell trying to find a command named `wget -c`.